# Azure multiple VM with same Virtual Public IP and Host name mapped to Virtual Public IP

Tags: azure, nginx, virtual-machine, cname

I am running following two VM's on Azure within same cloud service.

```
HOST NAME
First
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
104.xx.xx.26
HOST NAME
Second
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
104.xx.xx.26
```

On First nginx is running on port 80 and on Second no service is running on port 80

Now the question is :

I have mapped @ host name to above public IP(104.xx.xx.26). 
How would azure decide the VM the request to route to? 
Will azure route the request to Second VM where no service is running on port 80?

**Update :**

This Question is not related to load balancing!
I just want all my http requests to be directed to First VM and that's the way its working now.
My concern is how azure is routing the request. Can it route the request to second server some time, In that case response won't be serverd as no nginx is not running on Second Server.
I will using second server for diffrent Services.

E.g. 
First Server will have Php,Nginx installed
Second Server will have Mysql Installed

I want all the request on port 80 to be directed to first server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to route traffic between the two VMs of the same availability set you will have to setup a load-balanced set of endpoints, you can find all the gory details of how to do it

Click here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/

Answer (score 0):

Availability sets are not responsible for load balancing as [they ensure at least one VM within the set remains available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/).

There are [a few different approaches to distribute load in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/). For public facing services running on VMs within the same Cloud Service, the perhaps most accessible way is to configure a [load-balanced set for the service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internet-getstarted/). In your case, a load-balanced set for port 80 for both VMs. Azure will then distribute the traffic across both VMs using round-robin provided they run services on port 80.

Comment: The question is not related to load balancing.. my concern is what if my http request ported to Second vm

Comment: No. Though it's unclear to me how the availability set would benefit your setup.